# Confused about RDS CALs and other CALs and what exactly I need for publishing remote apps for 30 users?

Tags: licensing, windows-server-2012-r2, rds, remoteapp

I have an application which I want to publish using Remote App in Windows Sever 2012 R2.

I did some research and was able to setup everything in a test Win Server 2012 R2 hosted in Google Cloud. Right now, I can access remote apps like paint, notepad etc. which I added to test the things.

https://windows-server-2012-r2-1.cloudsentinelsstudio.com/RDWeb/

But I am confused and have no idea if I need any Licenses for publishing another app for 30 users to access it from different locations.

Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d6463a27-0d4f-4eb5-ae72-43ad23811858/confused-about-rds-cals-and-other-cals-and-what-exactly-i-need-for-publishing-remote-apps-for-30?forum=winserverTS

https://www.petri.com/forums/forum/server-operating-systems/windows-server-2012-2012-r2/494633-publishing-remote-apps-for-30-users

and bottom line is in my case I would need RDS CALs for 30 users.